# text/scanner hangs with IsIdentRune

Tags: go, text, newline, rune

If I have this code:

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "text/scanner"
)

func main() {
   src := strings.NewReader("hello\nworld\n")
   var s scanner.Scanner
   s.Init(src)
   s.IsIdentRune = func(ch rune, i int) bool {
      return ch != '\n'
   }
   s.Whitespace = 1<<'\n'
   for s.Scan() != scanner.EOF {
      println(s.TokenText())
   }
}
```

The program will print the two lines, but then it just hangs forever. I see this
in the docs:

> The set of valid characters must not intersect with the set of white space
> characters.

but it seems that I am following the direction given. What am I doing wrong?

1. https://godocs.io/text/scanner#Scanner.IsIdentRune

Answer (score 0):

IsIdentRune is called with [scanner.EOF](https://godocs.io/text/scanner#EOF) at the end of the input. Do not accept scanner.EOF as an identifier rune.

```
s.IsIdentRune = func(ch rune, i int) bool {
    return ch != scanner.EOF && ch != '\n'
}
```